# Problema con la lectura 8 byte de Binaryreader o FileStream

Tags: c#

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente:
Tengo un archivo de extensión ".epa". Sus datos son nativos.
Su estructura es la siguiente:

```
  //32 bits - NAEF

        //CICLO while (i < NAEF)
            
            //32 bits - Tamaño(en bytes) de la cantidad de letras de la siguiente PALABRA                
           //CICLO while (j < ALEN)
                //8 bits - CARACTER QUE COMPONE LA PALABRA
           //FIN DE CICLO

           //8 bits - boolean
           //8 bits - NAF(int)
          
           //CICLO while (k < NAF)
               //32 bits - Number Frame (int)
           //FIN DE CICLO

           //CICLO while (l < NAF)
                //32 bits * NAF - duracion
           //FIN DE CICLO
       //FIN DE CICLO
```

Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
   using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            int NAEF = reader.ReadInt32();
                for (int i = 0; i < NAEF; i++)
                {
                    int ALEN = reader.ReadInt32();
                    for (int j = 0; j < ALEN;)
                    {
                            long b = reader.ReadSByte();
                    }
                    bool flag = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.ReadInt64());
                    
                    int NAF = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadInt64());
                    
                    for (int k = 0; k < NAF; k++)
                    {
                        // FRAMES
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt32());
                    }
                    for (int l = 0; l < NAF; l++)
                    {
                        /// Duration each
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt32());
                    }


                }
        }
```

Y el erro que muestra es que no es correcto el tipo  de dato donde voy a almacenar los de 8 bits
"Se excede" o "El tamaño es muy corto"
Aquí la estructura en imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fichero usado:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/qv7dxeq8v3ny4bq/fotogramasMovimiento.epa/file

¡Estare muy agradecido con ustedes!